# Tengo un error al tratar de abir un programa de python en el cmd

Tags: python, python-2.x

Uso sublime text como editor de texto, pero cuando quiero ejecutar un programa que pide datos al usuario no me deja y creo que es parte de sublime; entonces siguiendo un curso de código facilito estoy aprendiendo a ejecutar mis programas con el Cmd; pero al intentar abrir mi archivo me aparece el siguiente error:

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file ./numeromagico.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Cabe aclarar que el archivo lo tengo en una carpeta llamada ejercicios y está ubicada en el escritorio; entonces en el cmd lo que escribo es: cd desktop>cd ejercicios>python numeromagico.py que es como se llama mi programa.

Answer (score 0):

yo también voy empezando pero le sé un poco a esto, espero te pueda ayudar:

En Sublime en la sección de File hay una opción **Save with Encoding** te despliega una lista con todos los tipos de codificaciones, lo más seguro es que la tuya sea utf-8, selecciónala y vuelve a ejecutar a ver qué sucede.

Igual puedes dar alt+Enter+siete veces abajo+Enter+Enter

:)

Comment: Mil gracias por tu pronta respuesta, he hecho lo que me has dicho y ahora en el cmd me sale lo siguiente: C:\Users\OvniGamer\Desktop\ejercicios>python nummagic.py
  File "nummagic.py", line 1
    Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

En sublime text el problema es que si voy a pedir datos de usuario de inmediato se ejecuta y no me permite escribir más código; por ejemplo:
numero = int(raw_input("Adivina el número mágico: "))
En lugar de seguir escribiendo de inmediato me pide el numer

Comment: De acuerdo a numero = int(raw_input("Adivina el número mágico: ")) 
me parece que está bien, tal vez si pudiera ver el código completo podría ayudarte más.

Comment: numero_magico = 7
numero_no_magico = int(raw_input("Adivina el número mágico: "))

while numero_magico != numero_no_magico:
 if numero_no_magico > numero_magico:
  print "ups!, fallaste!, intenta con un número más pequeño"
 else:
  print "Lo siento, intenta con un número más grande"

print "Adivinaste el número mágico, ¡GANASTE!"

Comment: numero_magico = 7 
numero_no_magico = int(input("Adivina el número mágico: ")) 
if numero_no_magico == numero_magico: 
 print("Adivinaste el número mágico, ¡GANASTE!")
elif numero_no_magico > numero_magico:
 print("ups!, fallaste!, intenta con un número más pequeño") 
else: 
 print("Lo siento, intenta con un número más grande")

Comment: Ese código a mí me sirvió muy bien, sólo que yo utilizo python 3.6.1 entonces no te podría enviar el código para python 2 porque no estoy mu seguro de que funcione pero ese por lo menos en python3 va muy bien

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, probaré instalando mejor python 3 que al parecer es menor complejo ya.

Comment: Amigo una pregunta, cómo haces para escribir código en sublime text sin que se ejecute él mismo cuando pides ingresar datos al usuario; me refiero a que te deje escribirlo por completo y guardarlo para ejecutarlo luego en la consola.

Comment: Sí, aunque bueno la verdad modifiqué el código porque el principal creaba un bucle infinito, y está perfecto que quieras actualizar a 3 sólo que una recomendación o advertencia como es relativamente nuevo no hay tanto 'soporte' para la nueva versión, por ejemplo no hay py2exe para python 3 aún mientras que para python 2 sí hay

Comment: Disculpa pero no entendí la anterior pregunta de que sublime ejecuta algo, disculpa

Comment: Me refiero a que tengo el inconveniente de estoy escribiendo un código en sublime, llego a una línea en la que escribo numero = int(raw_input("Dame un número: ")); y en la siguiente línea no me permite escribir sino que me imprime un mensaje que dice: Dame un número: y se queda esperando que el usuario ingrese el dato

Comment: La verdad no te puedo responder certeramente la pregunta porque a mí no me sucede pero es probable que tengas algún plug in instalado o algo así que depure el programa luego luego, o que tal vez el proceso de cmd no se haya cerrado bien o algo, reitero no puedo responder bien la pregunta. Que ahora, como recomendación yo utilizo PyCharm como editor, Sublime es muy bueno pero creo que PyCharm está más especializado a Python jaja

Comment: mil gracias amigo utilizaré ese